# fmt format specifier to print only field with non-zero value

Tags: go, formatting

Consider this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type myStruct struct {
    a string
    b int
    c bool
}

func main() {

    s := myStruct{
        c: true,
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", s)
    // print { 0 true}
    fmt.Printf("%+v", s)
    // print {a: b:0 c:true}
}
```

Is there a `fmt` format specifier to print only fields with non-zero value?

For example, with the code above, how can I print only

```
{c:true}
```

because `a == ""` and `b == 0`?

Comment: There is none..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in format verb that causes zero values to be omitted.

Here are some options.

## fmt.Stringer

You can hard-code the string format for your type by implementing [fmt.Stringer](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type myStruct struct {
    a string
    b int
    c bool
}

func (s myStruct) String() string {
    var fields []string

    if s.a != "" {
        fields = append(fields, fmt.Sprintf("a:%q", s.a))
    }

    if s.b != 0 {
        fields = append(fields, fmt.Sprintf("b:%d", s.b))
    }

    if s.c {
        fields = append(fields, fmt.Sprintf("c:%t", s.c))
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("{%s}", strings.Join(fields, ","))
}

func main() {
    s := myStruct{a: "foo"}

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
{a:"foo"}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Dw7F4Ua0Eyq

---

## Reflection

You can use reflection to build something that will work with any struct, but it is perhaps more hassle than it is worth. Example omitted.

---

### JSON

Another alternative is to marshal it to JSON, which handles the reflection part and has support for omitting zero values. Example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type myStruct struct {
    A string `json:",omitempty"`
    B int    `json:",omitempty"`
    C bool   `json:",omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    s := myStruct{A: "foo"}

    if err := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(s); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"A":"foo"}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/NcckEBNdnW6

---

### JSON with unexported fields

If you prefer to keep the original struct as-is; you can define a custom marshaller with an anonymous struct. Note however that the struct format is then duplicated in the `MarshalJSON` method which adds a bit of complexity:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type myStruct struct {
    a string
    b int
    c bool
}

func (s myStruct) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(
        struct {
            A string `json:"a,omitempty"`
            B int    `json:"b,omitempty"`
            C bool   `json:"c,omitempty"`
        }{
            A: s.a,
            B: s.b,
            C: s.c,
        },
    )
}

func main() {
    s := myStruct{a: "foo"}

    if err := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(s); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"a":"foo"}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/qsCKUNeFLpw

---

### JSON with unexported fields + fmt.Stringer

If you want, you can again implement [fmt.Stringer](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer), which `fmt.Printf` and friends will pick up:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type myStruct struct {
    a string
    b int
    c bool
}

func (s myStruct) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(
        struct {
            A string `json:"a,omitempty"`
            B int    `json:"b,omitempty"`
            C bool   `json:"c,omitempty"`
        }{
            A: s.a,
            B: s.b,
            C: s.c,
        },
    )
}

func (s myStruct) String() string {
    j, err := json.Marshal(s)
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }
    return string(j)
}

func main() {
    s := myStruct{a: "foo"}

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
{"a":"foo"}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/TPDoLOTAVJo